# trying to create region based memory pools in c

Tags: c, memory-management

I am trying to create a memory pool in this function which returns true if the pool is created successfully. 
This function is supposed to create a pool of memory with name passed as "*name" and size of "int size".

```
boolean create_memory_pool(char *name, int size)
{
  boolean task;
  task = (name = (char *) malloc (size));
  if(task == true)
    printf("task is true memory pool created");
  else if(task ==false)
    printf("task is false");
  else
    printf("unexpected");

  return task;
}
```

Its printing "unexpected" which means something else is happening.
I have defined the boolean as:

```
typedef enum{
  false,
  true
}boolean;
```

Comment: Why not use a real boolean type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `malloc`, `name` is a non-null pointer if successful, a null pointer otherwise.

So the expression `name = (char *) malloc (size)` has type `char *`, you are assigning this value to `task`, which should give you a warning because you didn't use a cast.

In a successful `malloc`, the pointer `name` is non-null, which is not the integer `1`, that's why `task` would be neither equal to `true`(`1`), nor `false`(`0`)

Actually you don't need `task`, just test if the value `name` is a null pointer:

```
boolean create_memory_pool(char *name, int size)
{
   name = malloc(size);
   if (name != NULL)
   {
       printf("malloc successful\n");
       return true;
   }
   else
   {
       printf("malloc failed\n");
       return false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it work use

```
  task = ((name = (char *) malloc (size))!=NULL);
```

Everything in C returns a value. and `enum` is basically `int`.
when you say

```
task = (name = (char *) malloc (size));
```

The expression `(name = (char *) malloc (size));` also return value. The value returned by that expression is pointer.

`task` gets the pointer value. So it is printing `unexpected`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to your problem is to make sure that `task` only gets a `1` or `0`, as opposed to your current code, which assigns a pointer value to it instead.  The following code will do just that:

```
task = !!(name = malloc(size));
```

The first `!` operator will convert the result of the `malloc` call into a `1` if `malloc` returned `NULL` and `0` otherwise, and the next `!` operator will change it back into the `1` or `0` you care about.

Alternately, use a real boolean type rather than rolling your own:

```
_Bool task;
```

or:

```
 bool task;
```

if you `#include <stdbool.h>` first.

Note: I also removed the unnecessary typecast.  Your current code should probably be giving you a warning about converting a pointer to an integer without a cast - you should heed such warnings and correct the code appropriately.  For example, from clang:

```
example.c:12:8: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to
      'boolean' from 'char *' [-Wint-conversion]
  task = (name = (char *) malloc (size));
       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, when you do something like

```
task = (name = (char *) malloc(size));
```

You're saying that task gets the same thing as name.  Since name gets the return of malloc, that's going to be a memory address.  So task is unlikely to be either true or false.
Instead try something like
    if(task)
      return true;
    else return false;

Secondly, name is an input parameter to the function.  your caller will not be able to read the output.
It's not clear why you call the name input name anyway; it's never used as the name of anything, and in fact never read.  Instead, you assign the output of malloc to it.
Which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

malloc returns NULL (ie, 0, in your case false), if it cant allocate memory.
It returns the address of newly allocated memory if it successfully allocated a memory, which wont be exactly 1. Your true is set as 1, so all values not equal to 1 will not be 'true'. That's why you are getting unexpected, even it is successful.

What you can do is

```
if(task ==false)
  printf("task is false");
else
  printf("task is true memory pool created");
```